# Oracle SQL Query to get the RAG

Tags: sql, oracle

```
RAG    PCT
------ ---
GREEN  100
AMBER   50
ORANGE  20
RED      0
```

I need an oracle query to result like (Suggest to use Inner Join or Outer Join)

```
if the given PCT >100 then Green
if the given PCT >=50 and PCT < 100 then AMBER
if the given PCT >=20 and PCT < 0 then ORANGE
else RED
```

Comment: To perform a join there must be more than one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the logic using  `CASE`, like :

```
SELECT pct, CASE 
    WHEN pct >= 100 THEN 'GREEN'
    WHEN pct >= 50 THEN 'AMBER'
    WHEN pct >= 20 then 'ORANGE'
    ELSE 'RED'
END
FROM mytable
```

`CASE` stops on the first matching condition (hence no need to write `WHEN pct >= 50 AND pct < 100` for example, since `pct >= 100` is already caught by the previous condition.

---

If you are using a separate table to store the lower bound of each interval (like 
`myranges`), as shown in your example, and you are looking to  `JOIN` it with a table that cotains actual data (like `mydata`), then it is a little more tricky : you would need to ensure that you are joining with the relevant range record :

```
SELECT d.*, r.*
FROM mydata d
INNER JOIN myranges r 
    ON d.value >= r.pct 
    AND (
        LEAD (r.pct) OVER (ORDER BY pct) IS NULL
        OR d.value < LEAD (r.pct) OVER (ORDER BY pct)
    )
```

Comment: Your logic doesn't quite do what OP has asked for. For example, in the case of the row with RAG='GREEN' and PCT=100, your code will return 'AMBER' while OP's spec indicates it should return 'RED'. Your code makes *sense*, but it doesn't implement OP's spec.

Comment: the Above one will not work for  case 2 and case 3 

 if the given PCT >=50 and PCT < 100 then AMBER
    if the given PCT >=20 and PCT < 0 then ORANGE

Comment: @BobJarvis : yes what to do with `100` was unclear since OP mentions : `if the given PCT >100 then Green`. I still modified for `100` to return `'Green'`.

Comment: @user8105857: how can PCT be >= 20 **and** < 0 at the same time?

Comment: @GMB: then you didn't implement the spec. This is clearly a homework question, and to be useful to OP we must strictly implement what OP has posted. :-)

Comment: @user8105857 : are you looking to join a data table with a table containing the definition of the intervals ? I provided a solution for that.

Comment: @BobJarvis : well as you pointed out there are some discrepancies in the data... Just trying to make sense out of it...

Comment: @user8105857 : are you looking to join a data table with a table containing the definition of the intervals ? I provided a solution for that. 

Yes

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't entirely make sense - you've said "Use a join" but have provided nothing to join **to**, but never mind. The following strictly implements your spec:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 'GREEN' AS RAG, 100 AS PCT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'AMBER', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'ORANGE', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 'RED', 0 FROM DUAL)
SELECT RAG, PCT, CASE
                   WHEN PCT > 100 THEN 'GREEN'
                   WHEN PCT >= 50 AND PCT < 100 THEN 'AMBER'
                   WHEN PCT >= 20 AND PCT < 0 THEN 'ORANGE'
                   ELSE 'RED'
                 END AS COLOR
  FROM cteData;
```

When executed, the above produces:

```
RAG     PCT COLOR
GREEN   100 RED
AMBER   50  AMBER
ORANGE  20  RED
RED     0   RED
```

And may Codd have mercy upon your soul.

Comment: here you have hot coded the values 100 and 50 and i am suggesting to take the value from Table itself, that is what i am asking you to use inner join like below is the query which i tried and working for case 2 and 3 but not 1 and 4

select RAG  from(select A.rag ,rownum from B3IDL_RAG_STATUS_RULES_MAINT A 
        inner join  B3IDL_RAG_STATUS_RULES_MAINT B on a.pct<108  or  108 >= a.pct and a.pct < b.pct or a.pct <108
        ) where rownum=1;

Comment: Query 

"
select RAG  from(select A.rag ,rownum from TABLE A 
        inner join  TABLE B on a.pct<108  or  108 >= a.pct and a.pct < b.pct or a.pct <108
        ) where rownum=1;   


"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think this might be something like what you're after:

```
WITH rag_data AS (SELECT 'GREEN' AS rag, 100 AS PCT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'AMBER' AS rag, 50 AS PCT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'ORANGE' AS rag, 20 AS PCT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'RED' AS rag, 0 AS PCT FROM DUAL),
  sample_data AS (SELECT -1 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 19 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 20 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 21 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 49 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 50 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 51 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 99 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 100 NUM FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 101 NUM FROM dual)
SELECT NUM,
       rag,
       pct,
       rn
FROM   (SELECT sd.num,
               rd.rag,
               rd.pct,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.num ORDER BY rd.pct DESC) rn
        FROM   sample_data sd
               INNER JOIN rag_data rd ON sd.num >= rd.pct)
WHERE  rn = 1;

       NUM RAG           PCT         RN
---------- ------ ---------- ----------
         0 RED             0          1
         1 RED             0          1
        19 RED             0          1
        20 ORANGE         20          1
        21 ORANGE         20          1
        49 ORANGE         20          1
        50 AMBER          50          1
        51 AMBER          50          1
        99 AMBER          50          1
       100 GREEN         100          1
       101 GREEN         100          1
```